# How to get a sum of in front of all numbers in multiple partition in DataFrame with Scala / Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a DataFrame,I want to get a sum of in front of all numbers in 'value' column.
this is my input:

```
+-----+-----+
|value|ts   |
+-----+-----+
|    1|    0|
|    7|    1|
|    3|    2|
|    3|    3|
|    5|    4|
|   21|    5|
|    7|    6|
|    3|    7|
|    9|    8|
|   10|    9|
+-----+-----+
```

this is my code:

```
 val arr = Array((1,1), (7,2), (3,3), (3,4), (5,5),(21,6), (7,7), (3,8), (9,9), (10,10))
 println("before get sum partition's number"+df.rdd.getNumPartitions)
 df=df.withColumn("sumValue", sum(col("value")).over(Window.orderBy(col("ts"))))
 println("after get sum partition's number"+df.rdd.getNumPartitions)
 df.show()
```

this is my except result:

```
+-----+---+--------+
|value| ts|sumValue|
+-----+---+--------+
|    1|  1|  1     |
|    7|  2|  8     |
|    3|  3| 11     |
|    3|  4| 14     |
|    5|  5| 19     |
|   21|  6| 40     |
|    7|  7| 47     |
|    3|  8| 50     |
|    9|  9| 59     |
|   10| 10| 69     |
+-----+---+--------+
```

but in my way ,all of data is collected in one partition,how to get the same result in multiple partition?

Answer (score 1):

Your expected result cannot be achieved by using `partitions` as the `sumValue` depends on the previous row `value`. **`Transformations` are done on the data that are present on the same executor. And the transformation you require is dependent on whole dataset not on parts of dataset.**

Your expected result can be achieved without partitions in the following way.

Given input `dataframe` as

```
+-----+---+
|value|ts |
+-----+---+
|1    |1  |
|7    |2  |
|3    |3  |
|3    |4  |
|5    |5  |
|21   |6  |
|7    |7  |
|3    |8  |
|9    |9  |
|10   |10 |
+-----+---+
```

You can use `cumulative sum` over `window` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val windowSpec = Window.orderBy("ts").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, 0)
val finalDF = df.withColumn("sumValue", sum(col("value")).over(windowSpec))
finalDF.show(false)
```

which should give you result as

```
+-----+---+--------+
|value|ts |sumValue|
+-----+---+--------+
|1    |1  |1       |
|7    |2  |8       |
|3    |3  |11      |
|3    |4  |14      |
|5    |5  |19      |
|21   |6  |40      |
|7    |7  |47      |
|3    |8  |50      |
|9    |9  |59      |
|10   |10 |69      |
+-----+---+--------+
```

**Updated**

looking at your comments and title of the question, you must have a `column` or `columns` which you can use for *partition*.

So give a `dataframe` as

```
+-----+-----+---+
|group|value|ts |
+-----+-----+---+
|A    |1    |1  |
|A    |7    |2  |
|A    |3    |3  |
|A    |3    |4  |
|A    |5    |5  |
|A    |21   |6  |
|A    |7    |7  |
|A    |3    |8  |
|A    |9    |9  |
|A    |10   |10 |
|B    |10   |11 |
|B    |10   |12 |
|B    |10   |13 |
|B    |10   |14 |
|B    |10   |15 |
+-----+-----+---+
```

You can use `partitionBy` as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("ts").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, 0)
val finalDF = df.withColumn("sumValue", sum(col("value")).over(windowSpec))
finalDF.show(false)
```

and get the result as

```
+-----+-----+---+--------+
|group|value|ts |sumValue|
+-----+-----+---+--------+
|B    |10   |11 |10      |
|B    |10   |12 |20      |
|B    |10   |13 |30      |
|B    |10   |14 |40      |
|B    |10   |15 |50      |
|A    |1    |1  |1       |
|A    |7    |2  |8       |
|A    |3    |3  |11      |
|A    |3    |4  |14      |
|A    |5    |5  |19      |
|A    |21   |6  |40      |
|A    |7    |7  |47      |
|A    |3    |8  |50      |
|A    |9    |9  |59      |
|A    |10   |10 |69      |
+-----+-----+---+--------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: My question  is how to get the same result in multiple partition,in your way ,all of data is collected in one partition.this is not my except result

Comment: it depends on how you want to partition? Your expected result says that theres no need of partition.

Comment: this is a example,In fact I need deal with lots of data,I have to calculate in multiple partition.

Comment: the first row'sumValue should be 79 not 10

Comment: thats what i was saying you cannot do partitions according to your requirement. Your requirement suggests all data to be present in one executor.

Comment: don't ya think thats too complex to be understood ? what you can do is explain the logic and accept your answer :) thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
val arr = Array((1,1), (7,2), (3,3), (3,4), (5,5),(21,6), (7,7), (3,8), (9,9), (10,10))
    var df = m_sparkCtx.parallelize(arr,5).toDF("value","ts")
    df=df.withColumn("valueSum",lit(0))
    println("before get sum partition's number"+df.rdd.getNumPartitions)
    var rdd=df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
      (parIdx,iter)=>{
        var sum=0
        val iterArray=iter.toArray
        val dataArray=new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
        for(data<-iterArray){
          sum+=data.getInt(0)
          dataArray.append(sum)
        }
        val result=iterArray.zip(dataArray).map(x=>{
          Row.fromSeq(x._1.toSeq.slice(0, x._1.size - 1) :+ x._2)
        })
        result.toIterator
      })//get sum in every partition
    val broadcastLastValue = m_sparkCtx.broadcast(new HashMap[Int,Int])
    val broadcastSumValue = m_sparkCtx.broadcast(new HashMap[Int,Int])
    rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
      (partIdx, iter) => {
        val dataArray = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
        while (iter.hasNext) {
          dataArray.append(iter.next().getInt(2))
        }
        broadcastLastValue.value+=(partIdx -> dataArray.last)
        dataArray.toIterator
      }).count()//get the last value in each partition into a broadcast
    var sumAll=0
    for(i<-0 until broadcastLastValue.value.size){
      broadcastSumValue.value+=(i->(broadcastLastValue.value.get(i).get+sumAll))
      sumAll+=broadcastLastValue.value.get(i).get
    }
    rdd=rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
      (partIdx, iter) => {
        val iterArray=iter.toArray
        val dataArray=new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
        if(partIdx==0){
          for(data<-iterArray){
            dataArray.append(data.getInt(2))
          }
        }else{
        for(sumValue<-broadcastSumValue.value) {
          if (sumValue._1 == partIdx - 1) {
            for (data <- iterArray) {
              dataArray.append(data.getInt(2) + sumValue._2)
            }
          }
        }
        }
        val result=iterArray.zip(dataArray).map(x=>{
          Row.fromSeq(x._1.toSeq.slice(0, x._1.size - 1) :+ x._2)
        })
        result.toIterator
      })//recalculate sum
     df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, df.schema)
df.show()
println("after get sum partition's number"+df.rdd.getNumPartitions)
```